# When imputing missing labels Y1 == NaN during training, how do additional target vectors (Y2 != NaN) impact learning Y1==NaN?

Tags: probability, neural-networks, bayesian, maximum-likelihood, gaussian-mixture-distribution

I am training a Mixture Density Network (MDN) to map from continuous input vectors X to continuous targets Y [i.e. X -> Y]. There are missing labels on vector Yi, which I impute from the mdn (as below). If Yi is conditionally dependent on Y2, does this improve estimates on Yi?

neglogloss = -MDN.log_prob( tf.where( tf.math.is_nan(Y) , mix.sample() , Y )))

I am generally curious on the effects of imputing any missing labels. Even a textbook or reading list is useful for me.